I'm an FNG: Strange SMB Share rwx Behavior Ubuntu Server 24.04
Forgive me for being a newbie!
(Also forgive me for taking 20 edits to get the formatting right.. first time for this, but I figured it out)
I've deprecated an old Windows Server 2012 machine.  I managed to stumble through about 90% of my Ubuntu 24.04 Server setup, but have discovered an odd thing with Samba (I've seen "millions" of "odd things" looking at forums).  I'm sure you all have answered "millions" of them, too.
So, I managed to get Samba up and running, with logins from windows clients working and the ability for shares to be rwx, and proper permissions.  However, my personal storage share I configured will not let me write to the "top level" folder of my Samba share.
I'm working on replicating windows redirected Documents folders, which is my use case here.  The goal is to have users be able to see folders, access their own folders, but not access other user's SMB folders.
I've successfully set up the file/folder permissions from the command line for all users.
(for reference, smb groups have been created for some public shares, those are fine.  I've used -e when I created the smbusers, and also restarted smbd after making changes.  Many times.)
Samba Version 4.19.5-Ubuntu
I have 4 users.  Other users seem to be able to write to their "user" directory, but mine can't.
Truncated smb.conf below:
[sean]
path = /mnt/storage/userfolders/sean
read only = no
browsable = yes
valid users = sean
force create mode = 0666
force directory mode = 0777}

ls -l for top level permissions, chown with -R to provide inheritance.  Inheritance to lower folders is successful, I'm not adding it here to prevent a mile long thread:
drwxrwx---+ 27 sean     sean     4096 May 22 17:01 sean

getfacl:
# file: sean
# owner: sean
# group: sean
user::rwx
user:sean:rwx
group::rwx
group:localuser:rwx
group:localuserro:r-x
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::---
default:group::---
default:mask::---
default:other::---

(I intend on removing the group permissions once I get this sorted out.  I did have this working flawlessly on Ubuntu 22.04 before deciding to do a wipe and reinstall to 24.04.  Yes, being new means really f'ing things up on occasion).
However, when I log in on my Windows 11 client, I receive the error:
"You need permission to perform this action." when I try to create a new file.
If I cd to the next level down (say sean/Bartons Docs) and attempt to create a new file from my Windows client, it works as expected.  New file can be created and deleted.
getfacl for Barton:
# file: Bartons Docs
# owner: sean
# group: sean
user::rwx
user:sean:rwx
group::rwx
group:localuser:rwx
group:localuserro:r-x
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::---
default:group::---
default:mask::---
default:other::---

ls-l for Bartons Docs
drwxrwx---+  2 sean sean     4096 May 16 21:19 'Bartons Docs'

I suspect I'm missing something on the top level "sean" folder that is available on others, but I'm pretty stumped.
I'm soooo close to replicating the Windows server experience in a workgroup environment!  And I'm proud to have done so with zero Ubuntu experience 3 months ago.
Any insights and help is appreciated. My bro is a Ubuntu/Linux guy and he's stumped as well.
Thanks everyone.  I'll be unavailable for a few days, but will check back after the long weekend.  Again, thank you!  I'm starting to love Ubuntu!  But small things like this finally caused me to break down and ask for community help.

Thank you for putting in the effort to make 10 (and not 20 :P ) edits to figure it out! Nothing to apologize for, quite the contrary! For next time, the information here might help: https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Thank you for your reply.  Yes, it was the first post ever, and i didnt figure out the formatting, then got anal about the info i gave, etc.  it is what it is, and it sucked, but i made it through.  I appreciate your time!

Ok, being a fng, i figured it out.  I had changed my pathing on the added mounted drive in fstab.  And i didnt update the pathing in smb.conf.  Yes, its the joy of bring a fng at this.
Now users have local access to their personal folders, and get prompted in windows and ubuntu to enter creds to access when using smb.
30 years of windows with few issues, and 6 months of ubuntu with a steep learning curve.  (Granted, I have faded memories of f'ing up windows, and hard disks on DOS back in the day).
So far i am impressed with the community, and how flexible ubuntu is.
Thank you again everyone, and those who responded, thank you all, too.
